# Failover MYSQL sync between two servers with different user name

Tags: php, mysql, linux, rsync, failover

I am trying to create a failover server and I have successfully synced the files between the primary and secondary server, but I am facing a problem with database sync.

I am using the following guide 'http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-create-a-server-failover-solution/' to create the database sync and I have tried:

> `mysqldump --host=1.2.3.4 --user=MYDBUSER -pMYDBPASSWORD
>   --add-drop-table --no-create-db --skip-lock-tables MYDBNAME | mysql --user=MYDBUSER -pMYDBPASSWORD MYDBNAME`

to achieve it. Now to the problem, the primary and secondary servers has different database usernames & because to this the database names cannot be same in both servers as in the cpanel we are forced to use the host username as the prefix to the dbname. Anyway I find it impossible to sync the database between these two, by the way the secondary server is hosted by hostgator and I think they wont allot me the username matching my primary server.

Is there any work around to sync the databases in two different servers with different usernames? Any reference links to achieve what I am looking for?
Thanks in advance!

Update:
I have found out a solution for this problem. Run the below line in ssh after making necessary changes.

`mysqldump --host=123.345.456 --user=primary_dbusername -pPassword_primary_db --add-drop-table --no-create-db --skip-lock-tables primary_dbname | ssh -i /home/primary_server_username/shell/id_rsa_primary -p 22 secondary_username@103.403.503 mysql -h localhost -u secondary_dbusername -pPassword_secondary_db secondary_dbname`

Here the primary database dumps the data and it is imported directly into secondary database. The database names can be different in both the servers. We need to set up a ssh without paraphrase for using cron job and identify the path to the rsa or dsa key in the identifier(-i). Hope this helps somebody out here with similar problem.
Good wishes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only sync the database that contains your application and the name of the database is the same on both servers, it really shouldn't matter that your mysql user is different.

If the database name for your application is different on both servers (which I assume it might be if you use hostgator, this answer provides some useful info: [generating database with different name from mysqldump backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993617/generating-database-with-different-name-from-mysqldump-backup))

Comment: name of database cannot be same. in cpanel the database name will be like: `username_dbname`. in both servers the dbnames are different because of this host username_ prefix

Comment: I was just thinking that, you beat me to it :)

Comment: thank for the input :) I don't think this link might help me. The restoration of mysql file is not manual, so even if they dont set the dbname in the sql dump file it wont get automatically updated in the secondary server.

Comment: I have found a solution: `mysqldump --host=123.345.456 --user=primary_dbusername -pPassword_primary_db --add-drop-table --no-create-db --skip-lock-tables primary_dbname | ssh -i /home/primary_server_username/shell/id_rsa_primary -p 22 secondary_username@103.403.503 mysql -h localhost -u secondary_dbusername -pPassword_secondary_db secondary_dbname`